# How to fetch the value of HTML tag id and store it in a variable using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Here is my jsp:

```
<h1>Drop Down Menu</h1>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                <select name="doctype" id="${rep}" class="my_dropdown" style="color:white; background:#655D78">
                                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc Type</option>
```

here is my jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var name = $("").val(); //value of the html id to be stored
          alert($.name);
            $.ajax({
             url:'',
             type:'post',
             cache:false,
             success: function(response){


             }
            });

        });


        </script>
```

I want ${rep} this value to be in jQuery function. 
Can anybody please help me out here?

Comment: Are you want get id when select tag selected? or select tag open time ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of select id (in your case: **${rep}**) you can select the element by [attribute value](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('select[name="doctype"]')
```

```js
var name = $('select[name="doctype"]').attr('id');
console.log('name: ' + name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>Drop Down Menu</h1>

<div class="dropdown">
    <select name="doctype" id="${rep}" class="my_dropdown" style="color:white; background:#655D78">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc Type</option>
    </select>
</div>
```